# Where is the flaw in this proof by induction?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction, solution-verification, fibonacci-numbers

I had a task to prove undermentioned property of the Fibonacci series.
 $$ a_2+a_4+a_6+...+a_{2n}=a_{2n+1}-1$$

where $a_1=1, a_2=1, a_3=2$.

For $n=3$:

$$a_2+a_4+a_6=1+3+8=12=a_7-1$$

Now let's assume that this is true for some $n$ and prove that this is true also for $n+1$.

$$a_2+a_4+a_6+...+a_{2n}+a_{2n+2}=a_{2n+3}-1$$
$$L=a_2+a_4+a_6+...+a_{2n}+a_{2n+2}=a_{2n+1}+a_{2n+2}-1=a_{2n+3}-1=R$$

It is proved! But then I quickly realised that $"-1"$ can be safely replaced by any number and the proof would still *look* valid. So what is going on? Are there any conditions that make induction invalid method?

Comment: If there is no $-1$, then the condition is wrong when $n=1$

Comment: There's no point on proving inductive step if it is wrong for the base step.

Comment: You wrote that you need now to prove the case for $n+1$, or to prove $a_2+a_4+a_6+...+a_{2n}+\color{red}{a_{2n+1}}=a_{2n+3}-1$.  What you need to prove is $a_2 + a_4+ \cdots a_{2n} + \color{red}{a_{2(n+1)}} = a_{2n+3} -1$.

Comment: Glad you made the appropriate correction, @1qwertyyyy.  You're welcome.

Comment: @amWhy thanks for correcrion, didnt see that ;))

Comment: An easier example of this phenomenon is proving $\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)=n^2+c$, which works iff $c=0$, since this is required in the basis step but irrelevant in the inductive step. Or for a simpler example, use $\sum_{k=1}^n1=n+c$ - or for an *even* simpler one, $\sum_{k=1}^n0=c$.

Comment: Since you used $n=3$ as your base case (and therefore proved the theorem only for $n\geq3$), it might be worth pointing out that your base case would fail if you changed the $-1$ in the formula. You'd get $12=a_7-$(something other than $1$) and that's false. (Some other commenters are thinking in terms of the better choice $n=1$ of base case and pointing out that this case fails if you alter the $-1$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what the basis step is for. Notice, you're proving a formula for all integers $n \ge 1$, and so the basis step is to check the formula for $n=1$. Once you've verified the basis step *and* the induction step then the formula is proved. But if you've verified only the induction step and not the basis step, then your proof is incomplete and, so far, invalid.

Here's what you might try to convince yourself. Start with some other recursive sequence that has the same inductive formula $a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ as the Fibonacci sequence, but has different starting values, say $a_1 = 2$ and $a_2 = 42$, so $a_3 = 44$, $a_4 = 86$, and so on. See if the induction step for proving your formula $a_2 + a_4 + ... + a_{2n} = a_{2n+1}-1$ is valid (it will be); see if the basis step is valid (it isn't); and most of all, see if the formula is true (it isn't).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you did the inductive step, or the inductive hypothesis, right.

The inductive hypothesis is: $a_2+a_4+a_6+\dots+a_{2n}=a_{2n+1}-1$.

Then if we replace $n$ by $n+1$, we get: $a_2+\dots+a_{2(n+1)}=a_{2n+1}-1+a_{2n+2}=a_{2n+3}-1$, completing the proof. The last equality follows from the definition of the Fibonacci sequence.

$-1$ cannot be replaced by any other number, because then the base case won't be true.